# Div not scrolling with the mouse wheel, but scrollbar does?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can anyone figure out why the dropdown on this page is not scrollable using the mouse wheel? If you open the first dropdown titled "Select Starting Location", you will see that the main list is not scrollable with a mouse wheel, but it is scrollable if your mouse is over the scrollbar to the right.

https://gasprices.aaa.com/aaa-gas-cost-calculator/

I've never encountered this issue before. Hopefully someone out there can figure this one out, I've had no luck.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you’re developing that page, make sure to test in multiple browser and operating systems. In Chrome on macOS, I cannot scroll the list no matter where my mouse is; the only scroll bar is for the whole page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the `overflow-y: auto` in outer div with class `.jq-selectbox__dropdown`

This single rule should fix the issue. Add it in your `ul` tag

```
height: 100%;
```

Comment: Totally worked! Thank you! So, was the issue because the mouse is actually trying to scroll the ul? Not the div? And since the ul did not have a height set, there was nothing to scroll?

Comment: Something like that. Scroll in div should work as it is. So this issue is little strange. Maybe some JavaScript in the jq select is messing with the scroll events in ul.

Comment: @footsoldier you can accept the answer if it helped you

Answer (score -1):

You can use this in your `ul` tag:

```
ul {
   overflow:scroll;
}
```